# Same top on many screens

Tags: java, android, view

I am building a small game-like app. It has a lot of different screens (is that the right word?). I would like to add a bar in the top with two info's. Name (of the player) and score.

What is the right way to do that?
I am thinking to make a custom view.
Can anyone make me a minimal example (say have two fields with different properties that I can set, e.g. name with small yellow letters in the left and score with bigger green letters/numbers in the right).

Thanks.

Comment: Read about fragments: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: This is not the right way to go here - people will not write code for you. Search carefully for a proper example, or try yourself, and if you need help with specific issues, pop a question.